# AS3 Casting as SuperClass returns null

Tags: actionscript-3, inheritance, casting, subclass

> **THE SOLUTION!**
>   Ensure that you're not mistakenly importing the wrong class.
>
> In my case, I was explicitly importing TabButton, but there was
>   another TabButton class that was being imported because it existed in
>   the same directory as TabButtonSubclass. This happened because
>   TabButtonSubclass exists in a folder specific to one application. This
>   folder also contains a horribly generically named class, TabButton,
>   which is completely unrelated and incompatible to the other TabButton
>   class. The application-specific TabButton class was renamed so it's
>   obvious it belongs to that application.
>
> Had I written *'public class MBTabButtonSprited extends **[specific
>   location]**.TabButton'*, it would have worked fine. But it seems that
>   since *'extends TabButton'* was not prefaced by a specific path, the
>   compiler defaulted to the local path.

I've been banging my head on my desk for a while now, trying to figure this one out.

My issue is that I've extended Sprite to create a TabButton class. I then extended the TabButton class (we'll call it TabButtonSubclass) for some additional functionality. When I try to cast an instance of TabButtonSubclass as TabButton, I get null.

The bizarre part though, is that I can cast an instance of TabButton **or** TabButtonSubclass as a Sprite, and it works fine.

Here is what my TabButton looks like:

```
import flash.display.Sprite;

public class TabButton extends Sprite {
    public function TabButton():void {
        super();
        // code
    }
}
```

And here is what my TabButtonSubclass looks like:

```
import ...TabButton;

public class TabButtonSubclass extends TabButton {

    public function TabButtonSubclass( bitmap:BitmapData ):void {
        // code
        super();
    }

}
```

**To clarify the TabButtonSubclass class:** The purpose of extending the TabButton was so that you could instantiate a TabButtonSubclass with a supplied Bitmap. This Bitmap would be used for various purposes. I have extended classes in the past and added parameters to the constructor, and it worked fine. Is this not a good idea?

Some sample code that illustrates my issue:

```
import flash.display.Sprite;
import ...TabButton;
import ...TabButtonSubclass;

var btn1:TabButton = new TabButton();
trace( "btn1:", btn1 );     // btn1: [object TabButton]
trace( "btn1 as Sprite:", (btn1 as Sprite) );     // btn1 as Sprite: [object TabButton]

var btn2:TabButtonSubclass = new TabButtonSubclass( new GangTabMail() );
trace( "btn2:", (btn2) );     // btn2: [object TabButtonSubclass]
trace( "btn2 as TabButton:", (btn2 as TabButton) );     // btn2 as TabButton: null
trace( "btn2 as Sprite:", (btn2 as Sprite) );     // btn2 as Sprite: [object TabButtonSubclass]
```

As you can see, I'm able to cast btn1 as Sprite with no issues. I can also cast btn2 as a Sprite, and it returns the expected results. However, if I try casting an instance of TabButtonSubclass as TabButton, **it returns null.**

I'm interested in casting an instance of TabButtonSubclass as TabButton because the application utilizes a couple of classes with that require objects of type TabButton to be passed.

**Here's an example of some code that allows you to type a class as a super class:**

```
import ...TabButton;
import flash.display.Sprite;

var myBtn:TabButton = new TabButton();
doStuff( myBtn );     // btn: [object TabButton]

function doStuff( btn:Sprite ):void {
    trace( "btn:", btn );
}
```

**Here's an example of the code failing if you go one level deeper:**

```
import ...TabButton;
import ...TabButtonSubclass;
import flash.display.Sprite;

var myBtn:TabButtonSubclass = new TabButtonSubclass( new BitmapData( ... ) );
doStuff( myBtn );     // Returns error: Implicit coercion of a value of type ...:TabButtonSubclass to an unrelated type ...:TabButton
doStuff( myBtn as TabButton );     // btn: null

function doStuff( btn:TabButton ):void {
    trace( "btn:", btn );
}
```

Can anybody offer any help as to why I get a null response when I attempt to trace it out? Or why I get that error? Am I missing something in regards to subclasses and type casting?

Comment: I might be totally off the track here, but is it possible that you have multiple swf being loaded and those swf have TabButton used in them?

Comment: Nope. Just one swf, catholiconless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Your code should work perfectly.** However this is not what other call the "best practice" when you declare a type of a function parameter as a Class. You should have **interface** for your TabButton.

You can **pass tons** of different **objects** to your function with one exception: objects **must have all methods implemented**, that your interface has. That's it. See [Polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_%28computer_science%29)

---

One possible answer for your question is:

```
public class TabButtonSubclass extends TabButton {
```

the **TabButton above** and the **TabButton below**  **are different** classes

```
trace( "btn2 as TabButton:", (btn2 as TabButton) ); // btn2 as TabButton: null
```

---

A key difference between casting and the **as** operator is the behavior on failure. When a cast fails, a TypeError is thrown. With the **as** operator whenever a cast fails the default value for the datatype is returned. [read more...](http://archive.darronschall.com/weblog/2006/02/actionscript-3-casting.html)

Comment: I'll look into this shortly and get back to you. Thanks for the words and links.

Comment: Actually, you are correct. My code should work perfectly, and it does. It seems there was another 'TabButton.as' class being automatically imported because it was in the same directory as a class that I was explicitly importing. Such a simple overlook on my part. Anyway, it's good to have it confirmed that my code is not widely accepted best practice, and I'll do more research into your suggestion and follow that route.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why it would return null, but the way I would handle it would be to rather define the variable using the base class and cast up when needed, eg.

```
import ...TabButton;
import ...TabButtonSubclass;
import flash.display.Sprite;

var myBtn:TabButton = new TabButtonSubclass( new BitmapData( ... ) );
doStuff( myBtn ); // No need to case here since myBtn is already defined as TabButton

function doStuff( btn:TabButton ):void {
    trace( "btn:", btn );
}
```

Then if you need TabButtonSubclass functionality you cast it up:

```
var myBtnSub:TabButtonSubclass = myBtn as TabButtonSubclass;
```

Comment: I just tried this one out. No dice. But, once again, unexpected results. I got another "implicit coercion" error. However, if I use the code:
var myBtn:Sprite = new TabButtonSubclass( new BitmapData( ... ) );
I don't get an implicit coercion error. I also don't get an error when passing this button into any classes requesting TabButton until a TabButton-specific function is called from that instance of Sprite.

Comment: Scratch that. I hadn't noticed my code read like so:
`var myBtn:Sprite = new TabButtonSubclass( new BitmapData( ... ) );
tabManager.addTab( myBtn as TabButton );`
When I remove that 'as TabButton' bit, I get an implicit coercion error from that line.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in AS3 and still learning, but perhaps this can help:

In your last code snippet, when you do

```
doStuff( myBtn );
```

and

```
doStuff( myBtn as TabButton);
```

what you are doing there is you are passing a variable with type `TabButtonSubclass` when the function is expecting a variable with a type of `TabButton`. So that's why you get the first error about implicit coercion.

Now the reason why you get a null if you try to `cast` your variable as `TabButton` when passing it into the function, I'm not really sure but I think it has to do with that if a `cast` can't be "honored" (i.e, you tell the compiler that the cast is valid, but it turns out that it actually is not, like if you tried to cast XML data as a movie clip, for example), then the result will be a null.

Hope that helps, but I could be totally wrong!

Comment: I tried creating a variable like so:
var btn1:TabButtonSubclass = new TabButtonSubclass();
var btn1Casted:TabButton = btn1 as TabButton;

It's still null;

Not sure if that's exactly what you were suggesting, but I have some new direction to explore. Thanks for the reply, Garry.

Comment: Yes, that's the thing. I don't know what data your two classes `TabButton` and `TabButtonSubclass` hold, but I'm guessing that they aren't convertible from one to the other and so you get null when you try.

Comment: All of the variables in TabButton are protected. I can't imagine what would cause a sub-class to be incompatible when type casted to the class it was inherited from. I feel like I am missing a silly and obvious mistake, but I can't find the solution.

Comment: Well think of it this way - if you tried casting a `MovieClip` as a `Sprite`, what would you get? The best possible result would probably be the first frame as a still image from the movieclip. So the compiler protects you from that. And the compiler doesn't know how exactly you would want the conversion to work (what if you actually wanted the last frame from the movie clip?), so there's no built-in way for that kind of conversion to work, as compared to built-in data types like int/string that CAN be converted because there are rules for the compiler to handle that kind of conversion.

Comment: Remember that inheritance works "upwards", so to speak, where you take somthing and build on top of it, giving it more functionality and properties. So if you tried to convert something like a car down to a bicycle, you'd be left with a whole lot of spare parts that the compiler doesn't know what to do with.
(BTW, in the comment above I forgot to mention that `MovieClip` is a subclass of `Sprite`, but you already know that :) )

Comment: That makes sense. But in regards to the "spare parts" comment, how could TabButtonSubclass become null when type casting it as TabButton, but it's perfectly happy being casted as Sprite? There would be even more spare parts, so to speak.

Comment: Ah, at this point I'll have to admit that I don't really know :( It's pretty hard to find any definitive information on casting on the internet, but the official documentation (http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f87.html) does state that
`For user-defined types, implicit conversions succeed when the value to be converted is an instance of the destination class or a class that derives from the destination class.` and gives an example, look at it. So you can convert "up the chain" so to say, but not down.

Comment: Now, why converting your `TabButtonSubclass` to `Sprite` works (even though it's "down the chain"), I don't know, but it could be that your `TabButtonSubclass` doesn't have anything that `Sprite` can't "handle", and so the conversion succeeds.
I would suggest that you post your two classes in full as an edit to your original post, and maybe someone more knowledgaable than me could take a look and give a definitive answer to this :)

Comment: I am sorry but this is totally wrong: "if you tried casting a MovieClip as a Sprite, what would you get? The best possible result would probably be the first frame as a still image from the movieclip." You can cast everything to an Object - the basic object of AS3 and nothing will be broken. Only issue that can happen - you will loose code hinting in your IDE.

Comment: Yes, `ZuzEl` you are correct. You CAN cast anything to `Object` because `Object` is a class specifically designed to be absolutely generic and capable of holding any kind of data. It is the root of the class hierarchy for Flash, afterall.
But you cannot cast a `MovieClip` to a `Sprite` - try it and you'll get an `implicit coercion` error from the compiler. Use the `as` keyword, and you will get a null if you trace the object after the cast.
However, you can do the opposite - i.e you can cast the `Sprite` up to `MovieClip` without issues.

Comment: My inheritance chain goes Sprite > TabButton > TabButtonSubclass. There is no MovieClip involved. Regardless, based on @Garry's suggestion, I decided to look into the possibility of Sprite being unable to handle code from TabButtonSubclass. So I stripped out absolutely everything, so it was basically just a shell with a single import. Then wrote some sample code that simply instantiates it and casts it as a TabButton (using the 'as' keyword). Same thing, I get null. But if I cast it as a Sprite, I get '[object TabButton]'.

Comment: I used MovieClip and Sprite to just demonstrate an example. Regardless of a class's content it could be that flash simply does not do conversions of Obj A to Ojb B if Obj A inherits (extends) Ojb B, unless it's a generic class designed to hold any data like the Object class itself.
I would suggest you take `cmann's` example or think about restructuring your program in a way that you don't have to mix and match classes.
Or, even better, in your `function doStuff`, simply expect a `sprite` object to be passed and pass in your TabButton that way. That, I think, should work (but I haven't tried).

Answer (score 0):

**Ensure that you're not mistakenly importing the wrong class.**

In my case, I was explicitly importing TabButton, but there was another TabButton class that was being imported because it existed in the same directory as TabButtonSubclass. This happened because TabButtonSubclass exists in a folder specific to one application. This folder also contains a horribly generically named class, TabButton, which is completely unrelated and incompatible to the other TabButton class. The application-specific TabButton class was renamed so it's obvious it belongs to that application.

Had I written *'public class MBTabButtonSprited extends **[specific location].** TabButton'*, it would have worked fine. But it seems that since *'extends TabButton'* was not prefaced by a specific path, the compiler defaulted to the local path.

Comment: To clarify any confusion: The MBTabButtonSprited class is the TabButtonSubclass class. My mistake.